# Create a file from ios emulator in a mac folder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, logging

I have my own log class and I would like that when a log is create in the emulator (or in the device), the log is written in a file in a mac folder.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fact files are created in osx folder. Applications are installed in folder: `~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/{iOS version}/Applications`.
Every application has own Documents, Library and tmp folders, you can get created files from this folders.